# Having trouble storing the string returned by the function in implementing tree

Tags: c++, string, tree

I am creating a tree consisting of different nodes. A node contains an int element, Node * leftchild and Node * rightchild. I want to store the structure in a string.

Node * root = NULL;

```
void print2DUtil(Node * tree, int space)
{
    // Base case
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        cout<<endl<<"AVL is empty."<<endl;
        return;
    }
    if(tree == NULL)
        return;

    // Increase distance between levels
    space += COUNT;

    // Process right child first
    print2DUtil(tree->rc, space);

    // Print current node after space
    // count
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = COUNT; i < space; i++)
        printf(" ");
    printf("%d\n", tree->data);

    // Process left child
    print2DUtil(tree->lc, space);
}
```

This is the code I've which works fine in printing the tree. But, I want to store the whole thing in a string and then print it. Imagine there is already a tree because I've an insert function which also works superbly.

I tried doing it myself, can you please correct it or suggest something?

```
string print2DUtil(Node * tree, int space)
{
    // Base case
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        return "AVL is empty.";
    }
    if(tree == NULL)
        return "";

    // Increase distance between levels
    string str = "";
    space += COUNT;

    // Process right child first
    str = print2DUtil(tree->rc, space);

    // Print current node after space
    // count
    str += "\n";
    for(int i = COUNT; i < space; i++)
        str += " ";
    str += std::to_string(tree->data);
    str += "\n";

    // Process left child
    str += print2DUtil(tree->lc, space);
return str;
}
```

Comment: The last code is my attempt in achieving the goal. But it is not working

Comment: Why not `str += print2DUtil(tree->lc, space);` in the last line? Also, `return` is missing.

Comment: please reload, I made an edit, is it now correct?

Comment: I don't know - does it work? Also, please take some time to read the [help] to learn how to ask good questions - this is not a code fixing service :)

Comment: OK :(  I will try to